# OverflowException with dotConnection PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, dotconnect

I've create model from databse using dotConnect for [PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/), proffesional edition. Everything works fine exception one of the entity. Some of properties were generated as decimal. Sample property in my `Entity`:

```
public global::System.Nullable<decimal> CollectionToPay
{
    get
    {
        global::System.Nullable<decimal> value = _CollectionToPay;
        OnGetCollectionToPay(ref value);
        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_CollectionToPay != value)
        {
          OnCollectionToPayChanging(ref value);
          ReportPropertyChanging("CollectionToPay");
          _CollectionToPay = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
          ReportPropertyChanged("CollectionToPay");
          OnCollectionToPayChanged();
      }
    }
}

private global::System.Nullable<decimal> _CollectionToPay;
```

When I try get collection of entities I am getting an error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred
>   in Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll
>
> Additional information: Value was either too large or too small for a
>   Decimal.

I don't know even which row casues problem. I'm fetching about 400 rows. Is there any fast way to determine problematic row? Table has about 170 columns, about 20 are of decimal type. I've fetched rows in pgAdmin, but non of values looks like too big/small. What can I do? I suppuse I'd change `decimal` to `double`, but first I need to find problematic row(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C#'s `Decimal` is a bounded type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx): it's a 128-bit fixed size value. Presumably it's an [IEEE 574:2008 `decimal128`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format) or equivalent.

This is *not* equivalent to [PostgreSQL's `numeric` type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format), which is what I presume you are mapping it to. (It'd be nice if you showed this). `numeric` is *arbitrary precision and scale binary-coded decimal*. Its practical limit is around 1GB, but that's so huge that it's an unimaginable number.

You can't store any possibly `numeric` in C#'s `Decimal`. Presumably your application contains values that cannot be stored in `Decimal`.

You may need to find a binary coded decimal datatype implementation in C# or adjust your data to eliminate the out-of-range values.

It's OK to map `numeric` to `Decimal` if you add a `CHECK` constraint to the `numeric` columns to restrict their value range. Personally I recommend doing this using a `DOMAIN` type.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to change schema or even manipulate the data. It's external system and I'm granted only to execute select quries. What's more, the max value stored is problematic column is `88919.999999883` and min `0`.. So the problem must be with precision. The number with the most precision is `6479.696856287425149700598802645`. Assigning directly to decimal does not cause errors: `decimal a = 6479.696856287425149700598802645m`. Maybe pgAdmin truncates displayed value.

Comment: Well, in that case you're going to have to identify which value is causing the exception in your code. A debugger may be helpful for this. Or there may be more detail in the cause chain of the exceptions (if C# does that like Java does, I don't really do C# much).

Comment: The problematic value is... `5670.074606244819010776457585128`. Unfortunately, `decimal a = 5670.074606244819010776457585128m` also works. Ok, I see. Value is rounded to `5670.0746062448190107764575851`.

Comment: Ok, I've found this: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=12506. It looks like it's still not fixed..

Comment: Wow, that's ... sub-optimal. They're right that the fix is nontrivial though.